# Selecting All Replies with parent comment using single SQL query

Tags: c#, sql

i have a table for storing comments which has structure like this:

comments

```
ID | post_id | comment        | parent    
1  |  1      | hello world    | null
2  |  1      | reply 1        | 1
3  |  1      | reply 2        | 1
4  |  1      | reply 3        | 1
```

i want to fetch the parent comment with all its replies using single sql query. 
currently i am using nested queries to retrieve the replies for a particular parent comment and i know this is not best practice.
i need to this to be done using single query.

my current sql queries snippet is:

```
parent_id =("select id,comment from comments where post_id='1' and parent='null'")["id"]

loop{       
      "select comment from comments where post_id='1' and parent= parent_id"
    }
```

i am using these nested queries to fetch the comments with their replies , what is the best practice to make this happen using single query?

Comment: All the entry has postID = 1 then why u check parent_ID or parent

Comment: postID = 1 means that all the parent comment and the child comments are belonging to postID 1. i need to retrieve the parent comment with all its replies using single query. to display the replies under the parent paret comment

Comment: by the way you are correct . i must figure it out ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query is enogh to get all the records(Parent + child) for a command.

```
select id,comment from comments where post_id='1'
```

Also, When you want to identify the Parent and child separately. Get parentID also in select query.

```
select id,comment, parent from comments where post_id='1'
```

In the c# code, you can find parent (parent is null) and child(Has parent as 1).

Comment: but here is a problem , i do not want to load all the replies at once , i need to display only 3 relies to a particular parent comment. now what ?

Comment: How you planned to get replies one by one ([123],[456],[789]). R you asking me how to identify each pack (3 replies)??

Comment: on page load there will be only 3 replies[1,2,3] for a particular parent comment. after that there will be an AJAX call to retrieve more replies for the same parent comment [4,5,6...]

Comment: On PageLoad use the query like select top 4 id,comment, parent from comments where post_id='1' order by id asc. Then at Ajax - send the last ID of the reply and query : select top 3 id,comment, parent from comments where post_id='1' and id > [LastID]

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
select t.id,t1.comment from table1 t inner join table t1 on t1.id=t.parentid
and t.parentid is not null and t1.parentid is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

1. Create a table based on your question.
2. Populate it with test data from your question.
3. Create a CTE query that returns results like you expect.

The key to the solution is the WITH RECURSIVE common table expression.

```
create table post_comment(
    id serial not null primary key,
    post_id int not null,
    comment text,
    parent_id int
);

insert into post_comment(post_id, comment, parent_id) values(1, 'hello world', null);
insert into post_comment(post_id, comment, parent_id) values(1, 'reply 1', 1);
insert into post_comment(post_id, comment, parent_id) values(1, 'reply 1', 1);
insert into post_comment(post_id, comment, parent_id) values(1, 'reply 1', 1);

with recursive comments(c) as (
    select * from post_comment where id = 1
union all
    select * from post_comment where parent_id = 1
)
select * from comments;
```